# How can I make for loop with > 10^11 iterations faster?

Tags: javascript, math, calculus

I am trying to implement 2 mathematical functions in JS however, I also need to to call `S(10**11) % 10**9` which takes a VERY long time. These functions are based off of 2 maths functions I have:
[image: d(k)]
[image: S(N)]
I tried just writing this into my calculator (ti nspire) however, it doesn't have enough memory which is why I have written this script.

I'm really not sure how I can optimise this, besides what I've already done, or potentially solving the summations, but I'm not sure how to do that with a floor function.

```
function d(k){
    var a = 0;
    for(l=1;l<=k;l++){
        a += Math.floor(1/(1+k%l))*l;
    }
    return a;
}

function S(N){
    var a = 0;
    for(i=1;i<=N;i++){
        for(j=1;j<=N;j++){
            a += d(i*j);
        }
    }
    return a;
}
```

Comment: `10**11 * 2` is a *really big number* and you can't just brute-force iterate over this.

Comment: Um `d(2 * 3)` is the same as `d(3 * 2)` right? So the second sum in `S` only has to go to `i`, then double the result.

Comment: Not sure if this will help, but it's possible to use GPU accelerated maths in JS,.. Have a look here -> http://gpu.rocks/

Comment: @JonasWilms so I could replace `S(N)` with [this?](https://i.imgur.com/srEJZQ2.jpg)

Comment: Thanks, @Keith I will definitely check that out, might come in handy for future projects, too.

Comment: This sounds like a typical competitive programming problem. If this is the case, then you should not try a brute-force solution. It almost never works. You should understand the logic behind this problem (math in this case) and find out how to greatly simplify it. Even if it is not a competitive programming problem, take a look at the `d(k)` and try to understand what it really does and if you can compute logically the same value more efficiently. Then see if you can calculate `d(i*j)` (as opposed to just `d(x)`) more efficiently. As the first hint: when `Math.floor(1/(1+k%l))` is not `0`?

Comment: @SergGr the function `d(k)` returns the sum of the factors of k, and is a function I created for it. Looking up other solutions to the sum of factors, I found [this](http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/71550.html), however I am unsure of how to implement it. S(N) is a function I have been given.

Comment: Matthew, yes, the idea is that you can calculate the sum of factors by first doing [prime factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorization) and then using a formula (see also [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/163245/finding-sum-of-factors-of-a-number-using-prime-factorization)). And since `k` is always `i*j`, what you can do is factorize all the numbers in the range `[1..N]` once and then pass pre-made factorization of `i*j` (just merge factors of `i` and `j`) instead of the value.

Comment: Well I haven't verified though, might be wrong, so I would verify that with smaller datasets

Answer (score 2):

The equations can be simplified quite a bit to make the calculations easier.

First you need to store the results of your d(i) so you never need to recalculate them.
Finding d(i+1) from d(i) is easy just use

The second pair of loops can be simplified a lot. Lets consider S(5)

```
           i
       1     2     3     4     5
    1  d(1) d(2)  d(3)  d(4)   d(5)
    2  d(2) d(4)  d(6)  d(8)  d(10)
  j 3  d(3) d(6)  d(9)  d(12) d(15)
    4  d(4) d(8)  d(12) d(16) d(20)
    5  d(5) d(10) d(15) d(20) d(25)
```

We can see how many values are recalculate. Firstly note how the matrix is symmetrical about the diagonal, giving a saving of a half. There is lots of other values recalculated.

Now if we look at the individual terms in d(k). First look at the results for mod(k,i) for different k and i

```
        i
     123456789
     ---------
 1 | 0
 2 | 00
 3 | 010
k4 | 0010
 5 | 01210
 6 | 000210
 7 | 0113210
 8 | 00203210
 9 | 010143210
```

Again cacheing values will help. Division is a relatively expensive operation so define a function

```
f(m) = floor( 1 / ( 1 + m ) )
```

and use this function with cached results when calculating the d(k). Actually lets calculate the values of f(m). Now f(0) = floor(1/1) = 1. f(1) = floor(1/2) = 0 and for any m>1 f(m) = 0.

This simplifies the calculation immensely. We are basically only interested in the cases where mod(k,i) = 0. That's the times when k is a multiple of i.

So d(k) is just the sum of the factors of k.

Rather than trying to find factors of k its easier to look at multiples of i.

```
for(i=1;i<N;++i) {
    // find multiples of i
    for(j=1;j<???;++j) {
       m = i * j;
       d(m) += i;
    }
 }
```

Now we worked out that d(k) is the sum of the factors of k, we can simplify the calculations of the S(N).

Bascially for a given factor m, we want to find all the cases where m is a factor of i*j.

Obviously, 1 is factor of every number so 1 occurs N*N times.
2 is a factor if either i or j is even. The product i*j is odd N/2 * N/2 times so even 3/4 N*N times. (I've assumed N is even)

For 3 if we draw the multiplication

```
*  1  2  3  4  5  6
1        3        6
2        6       12
3  3  6  9 12 15 18
4       12       24
5       15       30
6  6 12 18 24 30 36
```

and just fill in multiples of 3. We see there is (1 - 2/3 * 2/3) N*N multiples.

Similarly, with 4 there is (1 - 3/4 * 3/4) N*N multiples.

So the whole thing becomes a lot easier if we think about adding up the number of multiples.